# asking for CS coauthor as an undergraduate

Tags: computer-science, authorship

I've been working on a project with a graduate student in my lab for the past month and a half. I spend about 20 hours a week on the project.

I implemented a part of our algorithm, wrote part of the paper, revised the paper, tested/debugged the scripts we use for data collection, and produced some figures used in the paper.

Would it be appropriate for me to ask the graduate student for coauthorship? Do my contributions seem deserving of a coauthorship?

Comment: Naive question for people in lab sciences: can a student who participated in drafting and revising an article ever _not_ be considered a coauthor? I find this confusing since writing the article is the primary activity that lends the words “author” and “coauthor” their meaning (as defined by the dictionary in their broader sense beyond the strictly academic context). So it would seem to me that OP _is_ a coauthor tautologically, whether he/she asks to be one or not. It is not a question of being “deserving of coauthorship”, rather a matter of acknowledging a fact that is true by definition.

Comment: @DanRomik Yes. I asked a friend to check a definition in my paper, and he deleted mine and replaced it with two sentences he wrote. He is an author in your sense, but clearly does not meet any reasonable [definition](http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html) of scholarly authorship. The way to see it is we're talking about authorship as the conduct of the _study_ where the actual _presentation_ of the results in a journal paper only is a part of the overall work. (Without a study, there would be no paper)

Comment: @user71659 thanks. To clarify, I meant someone who wrote a substantial portion of an article. Writing two sentences of something would not merit coauthorship in any context, even in a very short piece like a newspaper article.

Comment: @DanRomik Looking at the ICMJE definition, an author must have made "Substantial contributions to the conception or design of the work; or the acquisition, analysis, or interpretation of data for the work". So somebody who solely contributed text, perhaps a technical writer brought on because the authors need foreign language help, would only qualify for an acknowledgement. Just like my friend, if they had given me a paragraph or two, they would get an acknowledgement, not authorship.

Comment: @user71659 yes, I’m familiar with these criteria thanks. I’m wondering though whether there is a _realistic_ scenario in which someone would invite their student to write substantial portions of an article without the student having made that kind of intellectual contribution. It seems to me that a competent faculty member would simply not do that as they would know that it’s a recipe for hurt feelings and other kinds of trouble. Hence my question above: do people really do that? I don’t feel that your technical writer example answers my question as that is obviously a different situation.

Comment: @DanRomik Exactly the situation I described. A foreign group wants to publish in an English language journal. Hey look, here's a student/postdoc from America! Please fix our paper. Another situation would be figures: hey, please make some fancy 3D graphics for us.

Comment: @user71659 thanks, that does make sense as a hypothetical scenario that likely happens occasionally.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Implementing part of the algorithm, running it and producing the figures, and especially writing a significant portion of the text of the paper, are all contributions that should count for a listing in the authors.

We can't exactly know whether your contribution to each of these were "significant" without seeing the paper, but it is very likely. So, ask.

Comment: In the case that my graduate student refuses due credit for my contributions, is there any justice? I'm very new to research and have heard stories of undergraduates slaving away for no recognition.

Comment: @everett Once you know the journal - you could always contact them saying that as a contributing author it does not have your name / has not been finally reviewed by you / contains your work without reference... But, think about the downside with that person - which may no longer be relevant as you likely won't want to collaborate again.

Comment: @everett: hopefully, the professor of your group would mediate in this situation. But IMO there's not really reason to be all that pessimistic - first authorship is much more important, and you're not asking for that, so the grad student won't really lose a lot by adding you as second author.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! To expand on the previous answer - I work in health sciences but a quick google for a computer science related journal and it's criterion for authorship indicated the rules are very much the same - from the 'instructions to authors' page for the journal 'Bioinformatics':

> Authorship credit should be based on substantial contribution to
>   **conception and design, execution, or analysis and interpretation of
>   data.** All authors should be involved in **drafting the article** or
>   revising it critically for important intellectual content, and must
>   have read and approved the final version of the manuscript.

Link - https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/pages/instructions_for_authors

Sounds like you've checked several of those boxes! If you want to be 100% sure about your case to put forward to the graduate student, identify the journal they're hoping to submit to so you can reference that authorship criterion, but I am pretty sure it will be along the lines of those mentioned above.